# How to get the participant to press a specific number key in python?

Tags: python, numbers, psychopy

I want to make it so that I present participants with numbers from 1-9 and the experiment will only continue if they press that specific number. So far I have this code:

```
from psychopy import visual, event, core

#draw the blank window
win=visual.Window([1024,768], fullscr=False,allowGUI=True, units='pix',\
color= (0,0,0))

#ready stim
ready = visual.TextStim(win, "Ready", color = (1.0, 1.0, 1.0))
ready.draw()
win.flip()
event.waitKeys()

#create text stimulus
tstim = visual.TextStim(win, text = '', pos=(0, 0))


for number in range(0,10):


    # Update text stimulus with the right number
    tstim.setText(number)

    # Draw the text stimulus
    tstim.draw()

    # Show on the next refresh
    win.flip()

    #note to self: figure out how to make it just for the number
    event.waitKeys(number)

    # Wait 1.0s before continuing
    core.wait(1.0)

# Blank the screen by flipping without drawing anything
win.flip()

# Wait for one seconds at the end
core.wait(1.0)

win.close()
```

When I do this, the code doesn't work as the wait keys needs to be a string not an integer. I have tried to do

```
str(number)
```

in the loop (before tstim) but that hasn't worked.

Can you help me to solve this so that I can get it so that the program goes onto the next number after the participant has pressed the number that is currently on the screen?

Comment: @Ioanna's answer is correct but the reason for your approach not working is that you didn't retain the result of converting the value to a string. e.g. you would have needed to do something like this: `number = str(number))`. The text stimulus is smart enough to coerce numeric values to strings behind the scenes, so you wouldn't have noticed the issue there, but `waitKeys()` does expect string values only.

Comment: You could simply do, IIUC, `waitKeys(str(number))`. Doing just `str(number)` without assignment is redundant and does nothing

Answer (score 1):

I converted `number` to string in your code here:

`event.waitKeys(str(number))`

and it worked fine.